# Spoofing of Server Sent Events

Tags: web-application, network, web-browser, webserver, javascript

In the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#authors) for [Server Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), it says

> Authors should check the origin attribute to ensure that messages are only accepted from domains that they expect to receive messages from. Otherwise, bugs in the author's message handling code could be exploited by hostile sites.

How one could possibly receive messages from domains without requesting it?

Wouldn't the fact that Server Sent Events are built on HTTP (TCP), make this impossible?

Answer (score 2):

That section of the spec is referring to [Cross-document messaging](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging), not Server Sent Events. It appears html5rocks.com has misquoted.

You are correct: If the SSE listener is not set for that domain in the page script, then there is no threat.